# Pull excel values and place in list

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I would like to pull the total sum of 1's in an excel column and place them into a list:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'filelocation')
t = df.col.value_counts().loc[1]
x = []
for i in t:
    x.append(i)
print (x)
```

The first parts of the code works and I can print the result of t, however when I try to place the value into a list I get 'numpy.int64 object is not iterable'.

This is less important but I would also like to make this piece more modular by being able to count the number of 2's 3's, etc and place them into the same list. Am i using the list correctly? Should I be using a dictionary instead?

Comment: Series and dict will do the same thing , may I know why you want change the value_counts result to dict here ?

Comment: do you mean you need to get the sum of every columns by `1's`, `2's`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, dictionary here is better:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4]
})
print (df)
    col
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     3
5     3
6     4
7     4
8     4
9     4
10    4

d = df.col.value_counts().to_dict()
print (d)
{4: 5, 3: 2, 2: 2, 1: 2}
```

Comment: Yes this works, however my problem is that I need to count the specific amount of 1's in df, which in this example is 2. {1: 2,}. If i try to use to_dict() I get my same attribute error.

Comment: @JacobClark - Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Do you need know if in your data is exactly amount of some value - e.g. if there are 2 values `1` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure why you need convert the `Series` to `dict` or `list` , if you need to I will recommend `dict` , data from Jez

```
import collections
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col': [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4]
})
collections.Counter(df.col.values.tolist())
Out[532]: Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 5})
#dict(collections.Counter(df.col.values.tolist()))
```

Comment: `df.col=df.col.astype('int') and collections.Counter(df.col)` should be enough and you dont need to convert the values to a list before passing to Counter

Comment: This should work, and would involve me specifying the column I want to use in the df = pd.dataframe. However when I do that is says "Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'f' (name of column where data is) was passed." I used mad_'s simplification as well.

Comment: I actually was reading the output of the dictionary wrong. Ex: There are 155 4's so it lists that first in the dictionary, how would I switch it to list the smallest item in the dictionary first? Ex: 1: 7, 4: 155